# R: Simulating a List of Customers

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following problem:

- Suppose on Day = 1, there are 100 customers (customer1, customer2....customer100)
- On any given day, there is a 0.5 probability that 2 new customers will arrive and a 0.5 probability that 2 existing customers will leave
- When a customer leaves, the index of that customer can never be recycled
- When a new customer arrive, the index of the new customer will be the index of the highest customer + 1

Here is my attempt at the simulation:

First, I initialized all parameters required (e.g. entry and exit probabilities, initial customers)

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
p_exit <- 0.5
p_join <- 0.5
customers <- sort(paste0("customer", 1:n))
max_customer_number <- n
```

Then, I made a list object to store the customers on all days:

```
customers_per_day <- list()
```

Finally, I wrote a FOR LOOP to simulate customers arriving and leaving over 100 days - this uses a random uniform number between 0 and 1 to decide if customers are arriving or leaving - then assigns an index to a new customer based on the maximum index ever observed (while sorting the list):

```
for (day in 1:100) {

    customers_per_day[[day]] <- customers[order(as.numeric(gsub("customer", "", customers)))]

    if (runif(1) < p_exit) {
        customers[sample(n, 2)] <- NA
    }

    if (runif(1) < p_join) {
        new_customers <- sort(paste0("customer", max_customer_number + 1:max_customer_number + 2))
        customers[is.na(customers)][1:2] <- new_customers
        max_customer_number <- max_customer_number + 2
    }
}
customers_per_day
```

This now shows the number of customers on any given day, for example:

```
[73]]
  [1] "customer3"   "customer4"   "customer6"   "customer10"  "customer11" 
  [6] "customer15"  "customer17"  "customer18"  "customer19"  "customer22" 
 [11] "customer23"  "customer24"  "customer25"  "customer28"  "customer33"
```

** Can someone please tell me if what I have done is correct **

Thanks!

- Note: suppose on day=56 we have customer 5, customer 99, customer 100, customer 101 ... if on day=57, customer 100 and customer 101 leave ... the next new customer will be assigned index 102 since 100 and 101 were already used

Comment: What determines _which_ two existing customers leave? That’s relevant if you want to know which customers remain, rather than just how many do.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably making it harder than it needs to be. You could do

```r
customer_ids <- 1:100
days_of_sim  <- 100
max_id       <- max(customer_ids)

for(i in seq(days_of_sim)) {
  
  max_id <- pmax(max_id, max(customer_ids)) # Ensures IDs never recycled
  
  # Note that if(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1)) gives a 50% chance the statement
  # will be run. Here we simulate two people leaving 
  if(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1)) {
    customer_ids <- sort(sample(customer_ids, length(customer_ids) - 2))
  }
  
  # Now simulate 2 joining with 50% probability
  if(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1)) {
    customer_ids <- c(customer_ids, max_id + 1:2)
  }
}

customer_ids
#>  [1]   3   4   6   8  10  11  18  19  25  30  31  32  40  41  46  47  48  49  50
#> [20]  54  56  60  63  69  72  73  77  82  87  90  92  96  97  98 109 110 111 116
#> [39] 117 118 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 130 132 133 134 135 143 145 148 152 153
#> [58] 154 156 160 161 162 165 166 167 168 169 170 172 173 174 175 176 178 179 180
#> [77] 181 182 183 184 186 187 190 194 195 196 197 198 199 200
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @ Allan Cameron: Thank you so much for your answer! In this approach, is it possible to see the customers on each day?

Comment: @stats_noob sure. You could create an empty list, say `customers <- list()` before the loop, and at the last line of the loop write `customers[i] <- customer_ids`. Then after the list completes you can view any day by subsetting the list, or just look at it all at once.